# Print string in reverse

Tags: c++

why isn't my code properly grabbing all my inputs? It only passes the last input to my function and reverses it. I want it to hold all the input from the user until quit is typed in.
I believe it's not actually quitting the program when q, quit, or Quit is getting read.
 I was told that using `fgets` (never used it before), would work but I tried using that and it didn't work, Probably didn't use it properly. `fgets(userString,MAX, stdin)`.

Example input:

```
Hello there
Hey
quit
```

Your output:

```
yeH
```

Expected output:

```
ereht olleH
yeH
```

Code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define MAX 50
using namespace std;

void stringReverse(char userString[]);

int main() {
    char userInput[MAX];
    cin.getline(userInput, MAX);

    if(strcmp(userInput, "q") == 0) {
    }
    if(strcmp(userInput, "quit") == 0) {
    }
    if(strcmp(userInput, "Quit") == 0) {
    } else {
        cin.getline(userInput, MAX);
    }
    cin.getline(userInput, MAX);

    stringReverse(userInput);
    cout << userInput << endl;

    return 0;
}

void stringReverse(char userString[]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(userString) / 2; i++) {
        char temp = userString[i];
        userString[i] = userString[strlen(userString) - i - 1];
        userString[strlen(userString) - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) exists. 2) reversing a standard container is as simple as iterating from `rbegin()` to `rend()` (or constructing a new container from those iterators).  Why is that not good enough?

Comment: @CurlyKid The code should not compile. break can be used in loops or in the switch statement.

Comment: Prefer `std::string` to character arrays in C++. Since it is also a container, you can apply standard-library functions to it. Note that arrays get converted to pointers when used as function arguments.

Comment: Did you print out the original strings to see if you read the input in correctly?

Comment: If you want to save all the input the user types then you got to add the latest user input to the data they've added before. Your code doesn't do that, it just replaces the earlier input with the latest input. That why you only see the latest input reversed.

Comment: @jesperjuhi strict rules, cant use that.

Comment: I'm not getting the output you claim to get with the given input. I get `tiuq`.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no loop in your `main` function so it'll do `cin.getline(userInput, MAX);` 3 times and reverse the last string you've entered, which is `quit`.

You could solve that with a while-loop:

```
int main() {
    char userInput[MAX];

    // loop for as long as cin is in a good state:
    while(cin.getline(userInput, MAX)) {

        // if any of the quit commands are given, break out of the while-loop:
        if(strcmp(userInput, "q") == 0 || strcmp(userInput, "quit") == 0 ||
           strcmp(userInput, "Quit") == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        // otherwise reverse the string and print it
        stringReverse(userInput);
        cout << userInput << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, I forgot you can put the getline in the while loop condition. Thanks, @TedLyngmo

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your question that you have used `break` at the wrong place. I suggest you to correct the code.

Also, you can use `strrev()` function defined in `string.h` header file of C to directly reverse a character array(string). There's no need to write different function for that.
For eg.

```
char str[50] ;
getline(cin,str);
printf("%s",strrev(str));
```

This code snippet would print the reversed string.

Comment: thank you for the response, i forgot to take out the break statements when I deleted my loop.